# ajax in jquery error : converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I console JSON.stringify(stateArr) my json look fine and look like this

```
{
    "shipping_options": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Kuala Lumpur",
        "rate": "222"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Labuan",
        "rate": "1"
    }]
}
```

but I got  converting circular structure to JSON error with my below code, I wonder why?

```
param["state"] = stateArr;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'example.com',
    data: {
        type: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(param)
    },
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data) {

        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(response) {}
});
```

Comment: @MeeneshJain converting circular structure to JSON error

Comment: What does the rest of `param` look like?

Comment: The crucial part - the (complete) definition of the param variable -  is left out in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something like

```
var param = stateArr;
param["state"] = stateArr;
```

This is a circular structure. Check your param reference.

Comment: That is speculation. Plausible though.